# Customize save() method in Spring Roo, how to access Bean attributes?

Tags: aspectj, spring-roo

How can I access the attributes of the MyEntity Bean in the after() method below?
for exampe if MyEntity has a name attribute I'd like to access it, I've tried just calling name but Spring STS indicates it is unknown, then I tried MyEntity.name but again it is unknown... Thanks for any help

```
package com.malsolo.aspects;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.malsolo.myproject.domain.MyEntity;

aspect MyEntityAspect {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyEntityAspect.class);

    pointcut persistEntity() : execution(* MyEntity.persist(..));

    public Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }

    after() : persistEntity() {
        logger().info("Entity persisted "+thisJoinPoint);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just one question, Do you really need create a pointcut?. On spring Roo you can customize the entity persist method just making _push-in_ into entity java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to access the execution context of a specific joinpoint selected by your pointcut, you need to expose it explicitly. One way to do it is by employing the "this" designator:

```
pointcut persistEntity(Object obj) : execution(* MyEntity.persist(..)) && this(obj);

after(Object obj) : persistEntity(obj) {
    // now "obj" is bound to the MyEntity instance persist() has been called on
    logger().info("Entity persisted "+thisJoinPoint);
}
```

You can also use the "thisJoinPoint.getThis()" method from within the after() advice. Note however that this approach uses reflection and is therefore slower:

```
after() : persistEntity() {
    Object obj = thisJoinPoint.getThis();  // now "obj" is bound to the MyEntity instance
                                           // persist() has been called on
    logger().info("Entity persisted "+thisJoinPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your property is private or protected. In this case you need a **privileged aspect:**

```java
privileged aspect MyEntityAspect {
    // ...
}
```